# Passing parameter to bottom tab component in React Native navigation 6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have code like below:

```
   const Project = ({ navigation, route }) => {
      const id = route.params.itemId;
        return (
        <Stack.Navigator >
          <Stack.Screen
            name="ProjectMain"
            component={TopNav}
            initialParams={{ id: id }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

Now how do I pass initialParams to my component TopNav?

My TopNav is like below

```
const TopNav = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  console.log(props.route);

   return (
    <>
     //my tab screens
    </>
  );
};
```

I am not able to get the params here, it's always undefined. How do I pass something to my TopNav component?

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct to me.

Can you double check that id (line 2 in Project) is not undefined?

What is the output of props.route? It should be an object with `key`, `name`, `params`, and `path`

Can you try using:

```js
const TopNav = () => {
  const route = useRoute()
  console.log(route);

   return (
    <>
     //my tab screens
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [options.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options)

```
<Stack.Screen
   name="ProjectMain"
   component={TopNav}
   options={{
      id: 'Awesome app',
    }}
/>
```